# How can i access the website running inside a Docker container using IP address of container

Tags: docker, containers

How can i access the website running inside container at ip 172.20.128.2 .I do not want to do port forwarding and using host ip.
I am aware that i can  forward docker port on host port and can access using host IP but i do not want to do in this way.
I am using docker 1.10

Comment: If you can directly reach the ip address, you should be able to just visit it, otherwise you need some kind of port forwarding, SSH tunnelling or reverse proxy. There is another issue that your web server might be listening on 127.0.0.1 only, in which case you cannot visit the website by ip without one of the techniques mentioned early.

Comment: Hello, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: I've created feature request - https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/31041

Answer (score 3):

This blog post explains many ways to reach your container from outside. Have a look [Four ways to connect a docker container](http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/).

Be sure your web server is well configured testing at least once with -p option.

Also you can test with the `--network host` option

Regards

Comment: The four ways are, NAT, and three different bridge-type technologies.  In each case, the idea is to go around the network mess that docker insists on creating, and going underneath.  None of these ways would seem to be sustainable with a docker configuration.