# How to access public IP inside docker for different containers

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

Hope you are doing well.

Prior Info:

I am using Docker version 17.06.0-ce and CentOS 7.3

I am running micro services based application in which I need to run docker containers on different public ips. Port binding is not an option for me (IP:80:80) because the micro workers are running inside container without any port binding. They are just fetching data from queue, process it and send again to queue. I need to run these workers in parallel on different public ips to run the process faster. I can launch different container with same worker application set but they all are listening on same public IP (docker containers private IP is different). How can I run different containers with different public IPs?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Why are you mapping the port at all? Why not run it without mapping the port?

Comment: I am not mapping the port. I need a solution without mapping a port. For an example, if I launch 2 containers worker1 and worker2 with same image both are working fine but they are routing through same public ip. What I need is, I want to run worker1 with public ip1 and worker2 with public ip2.

Comment: I'm also looking for this without any luck. macvlan didn't help me.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can find sufficient help in some other answers in the forum. Check these out:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35359185/5039312
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26953623/5039312
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35219070/5039312

Comment: I had already checked them. These are the network configurations running for private ip network (172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 is a private ip range) while I need to run containers on public ip. My application is not running on definite port. So port binding is not an option for me.

Comment: I see. Without port mapping things get more difficult. Maybe you can check this https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/ and in addition this https://micropyramid.com/blog/assign-public-ip-address-to-docker-container-without-port-binding/ 
I haven't used this, yet. But it sounds promising.

Comment: First link also is for private network. Trying with second link.

Comment: The _example_ in the first link is using a private network. But you should be able to use this technique to create a public one, too. This is described in the second link. In other words: the first link describes the fundamentals for the technique used in the second link.

Comment: Second link is talking about port mapping. I dont need port mapping. I need a solution without mapping a port. For an example, if I launch 2 containers worker1 and worker2 with same image both are working fine but they are routing through same public ip. What I need is, I want to run worker1 with public ip1 and worker2 with public ip2.

Comment: Tried macvlan too but it stops the overall networking in the containers.