# How to assign a public IP address to Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have read other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688906/how-to-assign-static-public-ip-to-docker-container) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container), but did not got my answer.

I ran this:

```
docker run -dp 192.168.43.80:80:80 nginx:beta-1
```

But I got this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint hardcore_babbage (aa327aefe662c502bbc79d01660c166198f9a08ad588cd946a794e02b0b07dc4): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 192.168.43.86:80: bind: cannot assign requested address.
```

And I searched for this error but got nothing.

`ip a`:

```
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:2d:eb:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.85/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 3060sec preferred_lft 3060sec
```

I use Oracle VirtualBox with three Linux VMs, and all of them has IP `192.168.43.0/24`.

I want to run a container that would be accessible via another IP like `192.168.43.80` from the VM which `enp0s3`'s IP is `192.168.43.85`. Both with `docker run` command and `docker-compose`.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Are you missing a second colon; `-p 192.168.43.85:80:80`?  Do you need the explicit IP address binding, or is letting the container be visible on all of the VM's interfaces okay (just `-p 80:80`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze that was a typo when writing question. I just want one container be accessible via a different public IP. container_a be accessible via 1.1.1.1, container_b via 2.2.2.2, etc. But if I did not specify, all of them be accessible via server main IP, like 192.168.43.85. I hope that was clear

Comment: You have three different IP addresses in the question.  Which one is the current VM's address?  Without Docker, how do you assign IP addresses to specific processes?

Comment: @DavidMaze The current one's IP is `192.168.43.85`. Regarding how I assign specific IP to specific process, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to solve:

1. I shut down my VM and enabled the second network interface.
2. Ran VM and ran `ip a` to confirm the number one and see new name
3. Ran `ifconfig enp0s8 192.168.43.80 netmask 255.255.255.255 up`
4. Ran docker container `docker run -dp192.168.43.80:80:80 nginx:beta-1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have added any other IP Address, you should do that:

1. Power off your VM. Enable a new network interface.
2. Run VM again and type `ip a` to see the new network interface name
3. Run `ifconfig NETWORK_INTERFACE 192.168.43.80 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`
4. Ping `192.168.43.80` and you should get result.
5. Now run your docker container via `docker run -dp192.168.43.80:80:80 nginx`
6. You should see `nginx` default web page or any other configured page when you type `192.168.43.80` on your internet browser